# DjangoRestFramework - Possible to allow certain requests only if request.user is viewing his own User object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my router / URLs:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```

I only want the user to be able to PUT, POST, PATCH and DELETE if request.user is his own User object. What I mean is, if a user goes to this URL

```
users/1
```

then DRF looks up the user whose pk is 1. If this user is not request.user, then I do not want to allow request.user to be able to POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE. If the user is request.user, then I want to allow those requests. Is there any way for me to do this? I'm using Viewsets and I'm hoping I can continue using Viewsets to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for accomplishing this is actually right on the docs page, at the bottom of [this section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing). To quote it here:

```py
@detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf])
def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
    ...
```

For that to work, you'll want to read through the [Authentication and permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) section of the docs, particularly the section dealing with [associating data with a particular user](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users), which suggests overriding the default `perform_create` view method to add an `owner` parameter:

```py
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

---

In response to the comment below:

The `perform_create` method belongs to the `GenericAPIView` class, which has the following function (quoting from [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview):)

> This class extends REST framework's `APIView` class, adding commonly required behavior for standard list and detail views.
>
> Each of the concrete generic views provided is built by combining `GenericAPIView` with one or more mixin classes.

`perform_create` is a function belonging to this generic class. Again quoting the [same section of the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview):

> **Save and deletion hooks:**
>
> The following methods are provided by the mixin classes, and provide easy overriding of the object save or deletion behavior.
>
> - `perform_create(self, serializer)` - Called by `CreateModelMixin` when saving a new object instance.
> - ...

So, the `perform_create` method has no purpose other than to provide an easy way to modify what happens when creating a new object.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question, where is the documentation for "IsAdminOrIsSelf"? I tried looking here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ and it is not there. Any idea where I can find it? I initially read through the "APIGuide" for "permissions" to look for that permission but didn't find it, which is when I decided to post the question.

Comment: @user2719875 - You know, I was trying to find an answer to that exact same question while looking this up and couldn't find anything. The best I can do is just point to the [source code](https://github.com/sebastibe/django-rest-skeleton/blob/master/api/users/permissions.py); it's pretty simple, maybe that'll be useful.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what perform_create does. perform_create is a method of the view class. It is called right after "serializer.save()" (in the view) is executed. It then does "serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)". Owner is now passed to the "create()" method of the serializer, but why is that even needed? In the "associating data with a particular user" section in the documentation, the create() method is not even edited to use the owner parameter. Wouldn't that raise an error saying "expected 2 positional arguments (request and validated_data) but 3 were given?

Comment: @user2719875 - Modified. The perform_create method is simply an empty convenience method in the `CreateModelMixin` class that makes it easy to modify things during object creation. Does that help?

Comment: Right, okay. But in this section: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#updating-our-serializer it says "owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')". So owner is now pointing to owner.username, which is a string, right? Because then, it the permissions class, the documentation does this: "class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
        return obj.owner == request.user". Wouldn't that always return False since a user object cannot equal a string?

Comment: @user2719875 - That is a very good point, I don't have an answer to that. I posted that question to the restframework IRC channel yesterday but didn't follow up to see if anyone answered, you may want to check it out yourself.